# Report viewer export to pdf doesnot embed font

Tags: fonts, pdf-generation, rdlc, report-viewer2010

I have a local report (rdlc) which uses Arial as the font. When I export the report with report viewer 2010 control (Winforms) to PDF it will not use the proper font. It uses Helvetica instead of Arial. Can font embedding be forced? I read that Report viewer 2010 supports font embedding, but how do you force this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Fonts are embedded in the PDF file when the following conditions apply (found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159713%28SQL.100%29.aspx)):

- Font embedding privileges are granted by the font author. Installed fonts include a property that indicates whether the font author intends to allow embedding a font in a document. If the property value is EMBED_NOEMBEDDING, the font is not embedded in the PDF file. For more information, see "TTGetEmbeddingType" on msdn.microsoft.com.
- The Font is TrueType.
- Fonts are referenced by visible items in a report. If a font is referenced by an item that has the Hidden property set to True, the font is not needed to display rendered data and will not be included in the file. Fonts are embedded only when they are needed to display the rendered report data.

For more details, try [this](http://www.networksteve.com/enterprise/topic.php/How_to_get_TTGetEmbeddingType_for_font/?TopicId=30923&Posts=1) the second post might be helpful.